# Heroku - Rails Change Root Directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am new to Heroku and I am facing an issue. My Rails application is not in the root directory where .git directory is. It is within **/backend/** subdirectory. When I try push it to heroku repository I get a failure message:

```
Failed to detect app matching no buildpack
```

I read that I should create Procfile to be able to control that but I dont know what should I put there.

My folder structure looks like:

```
.git
backend/
    app/
    config/
    Gemfile
    ...
frontend/
```

Comment: can you share your folder structure? are you hosting rails application on root of git?

Comment: Sure I've just updated schema

Comment: Why did you split your frontend and backend like that ?

Comment: what do you mean? Two separated repository? No, I dont want that.

Comment: this is a common mono-repo pattern

Answer (score 0):

`git subtree push --prefix backend heroku master`

Or, for those reading, replace 'backend' with whichever subdir you want to belong to heroku remote.